# Alamofire return string value

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i'm trying to write a method to return a json response from an API as a string. This is my code:

```
func authenticateUser(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    makeCall(completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

func makeCall(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, loginUrlString)
        .authenticate(user: "x", password: "y")
        .responseString { request, response, responseObject, error in
            completionHandler(responseObject: responseObject as? String, error: error)
    }
}
```

I can't compile it, the makeCall call in authenticateUser method says "Extraneous argument label 'completionHandler' in call.

I can't see whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just calling `makeCall(completionHandler)`.

From the error message, I would guess that that is what it is complaining about. Swift function label use often seems inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: It's working now, one question though, how can i call authenticateUser from another class? What parameter to pass

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean — you are calling a static class method on the Alamofire module/class which generates a request which is passed back as the return. Alamofire uses method chaining (always returning the original object from methods called on it) to allow you to chain several calls, including `authenticate`. If you want to set the authentication params in another class you will have to pass it the returned `Request` instance.